# console components not visible as a profile user

Tags: permissions, console, custom-console-components, custom-profile

I created a console and a Case page layout (with custom console components set up nicely). Everything looks good as System admin (picture below)-
[image]

But when i log in as a specific profile user (call it profile xyz), i dont see any of those sidebars or even the feed view (picture below)

[image]

Anyone has any clue what can cause this? There are no custom VF pages being used. Console app is visible to profile xyz
I confirmed that as a user with profile xyz, i am indeed looking at the right page layout. But somehow those sidebars are gone, along with feed view.

Comment: Did you enable service console checkbox for the user? Also you would check permission on that profile as well.

Comment: Yes Ashwani, service console checkbox is enabled and checked. User is able to use the console app. Within the console, when user views the case, things get messed up (look at the second pic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. For that profile in question, "Use Case Feed" needs to be unchecked, or else, it will cause this issue.